# Показать блок внутри списка при клике на ссылку

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
<ol class="rounded-list">
    <li>
        <a class="sh" href="#html">Верстка сайта</a>
        <p class="data">1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="sh" href="#php">Разработка функционала</a>
        <p class="data">2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="sh" href="#magazine">Создание простого Интернет-магазина</a>
        <p class="data">1</p>
    </li>
    <h5>А еще немного могу писать на</h5>
    <li>
        <a class="sh" href="#cpp-java">С++ or Java</a>
        <p class="data">1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="sh" href="#p-d">Pascal and Object Pascal(Delphi)</a>
        <p class="data">1</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Нужно при клике на ссылку класса sh, показать p.data  (дочерний. остальные скрыты)
искал, пробовал jquery toogle

Вот что я пробовал. Но открывает все, думаю здесь немного кода добавить и все будет работать

```
$('a.sh').click(function() {
    $("p.data").toggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: А почему у вас заголовок список разрывает?

Comment: а ссылки обязательно  чтобы были тэгом `<a>` ? а-то можно на css сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас выбираются все абзацы с классом **.data**, а вам нужны сестринские элементы.
Итого, **[вот решение](http://jsfiddle.net/4dyh9cp3/)**:

```
$('a.sh').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings("p.data").toggle("slow");
});
```